# Muliple choice option in skype channel botframework [node.js]

Tags: node.js, skype-bots

I'm searching solution form last week but no luck.

Can user select the multiple options in skype Nodejs SDK.
I'm looking for the solution where user can be able to select the more than one option from the choice list.

Let's say I wanted to implement the subscription functionality so the bot 
will pass the list of items to Skype client to view user.

**Choice List**

[image]

From above Now I want to subscribe the more that one item form list Ex. (Computer, Tech, Gadgets)

Can anyone Please help me to achieve by aim. If not possible can you please give me the actual reason.

Thanks :)

Comment: would we get a part of your salary for answering this question ? :P

Comment: @Sikorski If Client happy :) joke apart I searching from last week choice prompt only have option for stylelist but not other prompt. :(

Comment: you can try asking on skype forums if needed !

Comment: Actually this question is related to the node.js SDK with the bot framework behaviour. Skype forums is not useful here. but thanks for your suggestion..

Answer (score 2):

The ability to select multiple items in a choice prompt is not currently an available feature of the BotBuilder SDK.

An alternate way to handle this scenario would be to guide the user through a series of choice prompts where they could add a new item to an internal data object, or alternately store it in the `session.userData` or `session.conversationData` object.

If you'd like to make a feature request you can email: `feedback@botframework.com`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it will not suit to my requirement because they have long list of more than 100 items to select and un select.